# Backup Windows desktop icons, layout, background, etc?

Tags: windows, desktop-environment

I'm looking for an app to backup desktop icons, layout, background, etc, I was able to do it with genie backup manager in the past, which was an app to backup outlook express data and had that as an option too, is there any app to do just that (backup desktop icons, layout, background, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

[DesktopOK](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK) can store the layout of desktop icons
It allows you to store them in files or in an internal list.
I don't think it also stores background images.
Unfortunately it does not seem to store the shortcuts themselves.

Comment: this doesn't save the shortcuts, is there anything that can save the shortcuts too?

Comment: You're right. I always thought it diod but just verified that it indeed does not. I edited my answer above.

Comment: nevermind, I copied them manually

Comment: @patrickdrd and Erik. Welcome to Software Recommendations!  I see you are both new here.  If either of you find the question or answer worthy, you can upvote it.